# Expectations for a zipped static resource

Tags: static-resources

I'm scripting some deployment steps for sending static resources to my SF org. What are valid zip commands for static resources? If I'm running the build on a build server with a bash shell is there a recommended zip tool and arguments for creating a zipped static resource?

When I've done this in OSX I've used:

```
ditto -ck --rsrc --sequesterRsrc $sourceFolder $targetResource
```

That seems to work if I upload the resource directly via the Setup -> Static Resources in my org but I'm looking for something that will reliably work with the Force.com migration tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done something similar to Keith C's answer, so thought I'd include it here as well.

I've set up an 'unzippedStaticResources' directory within my project where I store the unzipped version of my static resource.  When I do an `ant deploy`, an ant task automatically zips up the contents and copies it to the staticresource directory before the deployment happens.

**Zip macrodef**

```
<macrodef name="zip-static-resource">
    <attribute name="zipName"/>
    <sequential>
        <echo message="Zipping: @{zipName}"/>
        <zip destfile="${srcDir}/staticresources/@{zipName}.resource" basedir="${unzippedDir}/@{zipName}" update="true" whenempty="fail"/>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

**To deploy**

```
<target name="deploy">
    <sequential>
        <zip-static-resource zipName="myZipFile1"/>
        <zip-static-resource zipName="myZipFile2"/>
        <sf:deploy ..... />
    </sequential>
</target>
```

Then when I want to retrieve metadata from Salesforce, I automate the unzipping of the static resource and copy it to the unZipped directory.

**Unzip macrodef**

```
<macrodef name="unzip-static-resource">
    <attribute name="zipName"/>
    <sequential>
        <echo message="Unzipping: @{zipName}"/>
        <delete dir="${unzippedDir}/@{zipName}"/>
        <unzip src="${srcDir}/staticresources/@{zipName}.resource" dest="${unzippedDir}/@{zipName}" failOnEmptyArchive="true"/>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

**To retrieve**

```
<target name="retrieve">
    <sequential>
        <sf:retrieve ..... />
        <unzip-static-resource zipName="myZipFile1"/>
        <unzip-static-resource zipName="myZipFile2"/>
    </sequential>
</target>
```

In this code I have a few properties set up:

```
<property name="srcDir" value="src" />
<property name="unzippedDir" value="unzippedStaticResources" />
```

I'm pretty new to Ant, so let me know if there's a better way to do things.

Ideally, I'd like the Ant script to automatically unzip all *.resource files (that are zip files) in the staticresource directory, and automatically zip up all directories in my 'unzippedStaticResources' directory.

Answer (score 2):

The [Force.com Migration Tools](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/meta_development.htm) are Ant based so it makes sense to use the Ant zip features such as [zip](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/zip.html) and [zipfileset](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/zipfileset.html) to create the zip file. These have worked fine for me.

Here is a random example from a project:

```
<target name="create zip">
    <zip destfile="phoneGapExternalContent.zip">
        <zipfileset dir="." includes="indexExternalContent.html" fullpath="index.html"/>
        <fileset dir="." includes="config.xml"/>
        <zipfileset dir="data" includes="Cv-Eep-120x120.png" fullpath="icon.png"/>
        <zipfileset dir="data" includes="Cv-Eep-640x960.png"/>
        <zipfileset dir="data" includes="Cv-Eep-640x1136.png"/>
    </zip>
</target>
```

You can make the output file a `.resource` file in the `src/staticresources` folder that following Force.com Migration Tool Ant targets can push into an org.